# ECS task unable to establish a connection to on-premise SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have a container running inside an ECS cluster which needs to communicate with a SQL Server sitting on an on-premise data-center, outbound rules of the SG attached to the container is wide open. What are the other possibilities do I need to look into?

While running the container from the local workstation I'm able to see a connection established with the QSL server. Below is the detailed error log

> "status":"DOWN",
> "components": {
> "db": {
> "status":"DOWN",
> "details": {
> "error":"org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: failed to obtain JDBC Connection;
> nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xyz.com, port XXXX has failed.
> Error: "connect timed out.
> Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."."}},
> "diskSpace": { "status":"UP", "details":{"total":265444,"free":155557,"threshold":764468,"exists":true}},"ping":{"status":"UP"}}}

Comment: You have Security Groups that you've configured at the AWS end. What about hardware and software firewalls at your on-prem end?

Comment: We have the other services/tools that are able to establish connection from on-Prem to aws, So that’s a sign or confirmation from on-Prem side that it’s allowing connections from aws

Comment: Firewalls have separate rules for ingress and egress traffic. Just because you can connect from on-prem to AWS doesn't mean you can go the other way.

Comment: Fargate or EC2? Are you using awsvpc n/w mode? If yes, make sure that the task is launched in a private subnet with NAT gateway.

Comment: awsvpc and task is running inside private subnet

Comment: You said, "We have the other services/tools that are able to establish connection from on-Prem to aws, So that’s a sign or confirmation from on-Prem side that it’s allowing connections from aws". However -- that's not necessarily true. Just because on-prem can connect to AWS doesn't mean AWS can connect to an on-prem server deep in your data center. I find it unlikely that you have a SQL server just sitting on the internet waiting for anyone to connect to it. Have you talked to your on-prem networking people?

Comment: Network team mention that the NACL's and other rules on the AWS have the right settings to establish a connection to on-prem, I'm not sure if something needs to be modified on the data-center side

Answer (score 0):

ECS fargate is using an DNS which was not resolvable, I have added that to route53 which resolved the issue